# How to find specific buildings in a city

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

I have been looking for a shop for 23 adventures now ; I cannot find where buildings are, because apparently aside from the orange areas in cities that only have houses and a well there are no letters, markers, or anything.

I have died of starvation and thirst 23 times now, because I don't even have a waterskin.

**How can I find the special buildings (especially the shop) of a city ?**

Comment: Please mind your language. We like to keep things verbally clean here.

Comment: You should start with a waterskin, unless maybe you are playing as a human outsider (in which case you're going to have a hard time any way you put it). Also you don't need a waterskin to drink; you can drink directly from the river.

Answer (score 1):

For water, drink from the well (<kbd>u</kbd>se the well to lower the bucket, then again to raise it, then <kbd>I</kbd>nteract with your waterskin to fill it), your waterskin (<kbd>e</kbd>, then choose the water), or the river (straight <kbd>e</kbd>, but you can also <kbd>I</kbd>nteract with your waterskin to fill it).

You can butcher (<kbd>x</kbd>, then press <kbd>right</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>, and you'll see the meat at your feet) dead things for meat, as well as finding plants and meat in just plain old homes.